# extjs - set grid column's width wide enough to display text in it

Tags: extjs, grid

I am loading a grid dynamically in extjs. As you can see below the column "Created" is not wide enough to display whole text in it. I want to set every column's width such that it display's its text completely.

[image]

Is this possible to do? Any suggestion?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks bensiu, I implemented the login. However, I cannot say that this is the ideal solution but it solves my purpose.

First, i navigate through data and find the longest string in that column (including header name of that column).

```
// Store the longest string for each column in columns[col].maxstring 

// Define a hidden label
{
    xtype: 'label',
    id: 'lblTab',
    hidden: true
}

var lblTab = Ext.getCmp('lblTab');
var hiddenField = Ext.util.TextMetrics.createInstance(Ext.getCmp('lblTab').el);
var widthValue = 0;

// Iterate through each columns to set its maximum width
for(var col in columns) {
    // find width of string
    widthValue = hiddenField.getWidth(columns[col].maxstring);

    // set column width
    colModel.setColumnWidth(columns[col].index, widthValue + 20, false);  
}
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

use parameter `width: ...` with your column config. As simple as this. I do not see your code so I am guessing.

However it look like you have more vertical space -> maybe break date in 2 lines (using template) would be solution, or you can have special css class just for this cell with smaller letter in order to fit.

**Edit:**
in your case it could be combination of defaultWith in ColumnModel (at least get 120 to fit your date, if more columns grid would adjust) and setColumnWith() dynamically based on length of data and number of columns - logic is up to you

Comment: hi thanks for replying. I cannot use "width:" as i m loading grid dynamically and it has many columns so i can't guess its width. Also, I want everything in 1 line only (extra vertical space is due to image in that column). Regards